# in Angular 13, How can i call inner child component to parent component with dependency resolve ? what is the best approach to refresh grid data?

Tags: angular, typescript

**I have UserViewComponent , after i open an modal by calling openSelectUserModal() , SelectUserComponent will open. then here i have to open another modal that is AddUserComponent.  after opening AddUserComponent , Here is a method addUser(). here i need to call UserViewComponent.ngOnInit() with dependency resolve . how to do it in efficient way ???**

```
rows:any[];
columns: any[]
page: IPagination;



export class UserViewComponent {
    constructor(private userService: UserService, private alertService: AlertService)
    ngOnInit() {
        this.projectId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('projectId');
        this.loadCommonService();
        this.loadTableSetting();
        this.getUsers();
    }

    getUsers() {
        this.userService.getUsers(this.page, this.projectId).subscribe({
            next: res => {
                this.loadViewData(res);
            }
        });
    }

    loadViewData(result: PaginatedViewModel) {
        this.columns = [];
        this.rows = [];
        this.page.count = result.count;
        this.page.pageNo = result.pageNo;
        this.page.pageSize = result.pageSize;

        this.generatePropertyColumns(result.columns);
        this.generatePropertyRows(result);
        this.loadTableSetting();
    }

    openSelectUserModal() {
        this.modalService.Open<SelectUserComponent>()
    }
}

export class SelectUserComponent(){
    openAddUserModal(){
        this.modalService.Open<AddUserComponent>()
    }
}

export class AddUserComponent {
    addUser() {
        this.userService.createUser(model).then((res) => {
            let id = res.id;

            // Here I need to call UserViewComponent.ngOnInit()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is there inside the `ngOnInit` method of the `UserViewComponent` that you need to call? Can you include the code in that method?

Comment: Calling an service to get the data . Then some processing to view the data into table. When i first route to /users , this component ngOnInit calls , so i need to call it from addUserComponent . Here the code could be - this.userService.getAll().subscribe(res) { next: this.rows = result.data

Comment: You're making it too complicated, you only need to refresh the data; there are many ways of doing it. Accessing the component to call ngOnInit on it again is one of the least convenient ways of doing it.

Comment: Ues, you have understand my main problem . I have updated my code but couldn't understand how to do it with to refresh the data and table settings . how could i implement it ?

Comment: Return the promise to the caller or fetch data on modal close or fetch data every x seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Subject in your service, then subscribe to this Subject.

```
//in your Service
change:Subject<void>=new Subject<void>(); //declare a Subject

//each change you use
this.change.next();
```

Now in your UserViewComponent  subscribe to userService.change using swithMap to return the getUser and use startWith to get initial value

```
   getUsers() {
   //not subscribe to this.userService.getUser else "change"
   this.userService.change.pipe(
      //you use startWith to initial value
      startWith(null),    

      //you use switchMap to return the 
      //observable "userService.getUsers()"
      switchMap(_=>this.userService.getUsers(this.page, this.projectId)) 
   )
   .subscribe({
            next: res => {
                this.loadViewData(res);
            }
        });
    }
```

A [simple stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y4tc1j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts)